# Parent to child checkbox selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I am trying to set up and parent to child selection with checkboxes and if a child element has been selected, the parent has an indeterminate (minus).

**HTML structure**

```html
    <ul>
      <li>
        <label for="redskins">
        <input type="checkbox" name="redskins" id="redskins">
        Redskins</label>

        <ul>
          <li>     <label for="cheifs">
            <input type="checkbox" name="cheifs" id="cheifs">
            <label for="cheifs">Cheifs</label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <label for="vikings"><input type="checkbox" name="vikings" id="vikings">
            Vikings</label>


          </li>
          <li>
             <label for="jets"><input type="checkbox" name="jets" id="jets">
           Jets</label>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for="packers">
        <input type="checkbox" name="packers" id="packers">
        Packers</label>

        <ul>
          <li>     <label for="chargers">
            <input type="checkbox" name="chargers" id="chargers">
            <label for="chargers">Chargers</label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <label for="giants"><input type="checkbox" name="giants" id="giants">
            Giants</label>


          </li>
          <li>
             <label for="jets"><input type="checkbox" name="jets" id="jets">
           Jets</label>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

**Javascript (jQuery)**

```
      $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(e) {

      var checked = $(this).prop("checked"),
      container = $(this).parent(),
      siblings = container.siblings();

      container.find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop({
       indeterminate: false,
       checked: checked
    });

    function checkSiblings(el) {

    var parent = el.parent().parent(),
        all = true;
  console.log(parent);
    el.siblings().each(function() {
      console.log($(this))
      let returnValue = all = ($(this).children('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked") === checked);
      return returnValue;
    });

    if (all && checked) {
      console.log(parent.children('input[type="checkbox"]'));
      parent.children('input[type="checkbox"]').prop({
        indeterminate: false,
        checked: checked
      });
console.log(parent);
      checkSiblings(parent);

    } else if (all && !checked) {

      parent.children('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked", checked);
      parent.children('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("indeterminate", (parent.find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length > 0));
      console.log(parent);
      checkSiblings(parent);

    } else {

      el.parents("li").children('input[type="checkbox"]').prop({
        indeterminate: true,
        checked: false
      });

    }

  }

  checkSiblings(container);
});
```

https://codepen.io/kkashou/pen/KKPZORP

Here is the code I have set up at the moment.

Let me know what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Note that it makes it easier for people to answer when you include all necessary code to reproduce the issue in the question itself, rather than only some here and the rest on an external site. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I was getting errors saying too much code in content but i was able to add it now. @HereticMonkey

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution looks too complicated here is a simple version,

You need to identify first if the parent or child checkbox is changed, then respectively flow the result to concerned parties.

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function (e) {
  var checked = $(this).prop('checked');
  var isParent = !!$(this).closest('li').find(' > ul').length;
  if (isParent) {
    // if a parent level checkbox is changed, locate all children
    var children = $(this).closest('li').find('ul input[type=checkbox]');
    children.prop({
      checked
    }); // all children will have what parent has
  } else {
    // if a child checkbox is changed, locate parent and all children
    var parent = $(this).closest('ul').closest('li').find('>label input[type=checkbox]');
    var children = $(this).closest('ul').find('input[type=checkbox]');
    if (children.filter(':checked').length === 0) {
      // if all children are unchecked
      parent.prop({ checked: false, indeterminate: false });
    } else if (children.length === children.filter(':checked').length) {
      // if all children are checked
      parent.prop({ checked: true, indeterminate: false });
    } else {
      // if some of the children are checked
      parent.prop({ checked: true, indeterminate: true });
    }
  }
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 5px 20px;
}

li {
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <label for="redskins">
      <input type="checkbox" name="redskins" id="redskins">
      Redskins</label>

    <ul>
      <li> <label for="cheifs">
          <input type="checkbox" name="cheifs" id="cheifs">
          <label for="cheifs">Cheifs</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for="vikings"><input type="checkbox" name="vikings" id="vikings">
          Vikings</label>


      </li>
      <li>
        <label for="bears"><input type="checkbox" name="bears" id="bears">
          Bears</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="packers">
      <input type="checkbox" name="packers" id="packers">
      Packers</label>

    <ul>
      <li> <label for="chargers">
          <input type="checkbox" name="chargers" id="chargers">
          <label for="chargers">Chargers</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for="giants"><input type="checkbox" name="giants" id="giants">
          Giants</label>


      </li>
      <li>
        <label for="jets"><input type="checkbox" name="jets" id="jets">
          Jets</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```